# Como abrir um servidor local usando node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, localhost

Quero abrir um servidor local para testar meu projeto em ReactJS, mas quero que eu possa tanto ver ele localmente na minha máquina quanto em outro computador.

Eu tenho que abrir alguma porta?

**Edit:** Os dois usando a mesma rede.

Comment: Este outro "Computador" está na mesma rede?

Comment: Os dois usando a mesma rede

Comment: Basta pegar o seu ip local (192.168...) e acessar pelo outro computador com a porta configurada no servidor principal. Lembre-se de abrir as portas no firewall dos computadores. (Caso use o windows, desative-o temporariamente, caso use linux, crie exceção no iptables)

Comment: Vou tentar, tem algum modo sem usar portas ?  setar para não usar nenhuma ?

Eu já usei o XAMP para alguns testes e transferir arquivos conectando direto no ip da maquina.

Comment: desligue o firewall a porta se abrirá

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sempre que você carrega uma URL sem especificar o número da porta, o padrão do navegador é `80`, porque `80` é o número da porta padrão para `HTTP`.

Portanto, se você carregar http://stackoverflow.com/questions, o navegador "converte" em http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions.

Se você não quiser que um número de porta seja especificado para acessar seu site, seu aplicativo deve estar escutando na porta `80`, em vez de `3000`.

```
// app.js

const http = require('http');

// Crie uma instância do servidor http para manipular solicitações HTTP
let app = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    res.end('Hello World!\n');
});

// Inicie o servidor na porta 80
app.listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
```

No entanto, não é recomendado para aplicativos do Node escutar diretamente na porta `80` (**embora eles possam muito bem**).

Agora se quiser acessar o site através de um outro computador que está na mesma rede:

> **@Paulo Victor** Basta pegar o seu ip local (192.168...) e acessar pelo outro computador com a porta configurada no servidor principal. Lembre-se de abrir as portas no firewall dos computadores. (Caso use o windows, desative-o temporariamente, caso use linux, crie exceção no iptables)

Em muitos casos quando tentar correr o **Nodejs** na porta `80` vai dar erro do tipo `Error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:80`.

Entretanto, para ultrapassar essa questão podes usar um [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) voltado para a frente, como [**nginx**](https://www.nginx.com/), que aceita conexões com a porta `80` do host e, em seguida, redireciona a solicitação para `localhost: 3000`, onde seu aplicativo está escutando.

Answer (score 1):

Outra solução é usar o https://nextjs.org/ :)

Com alguns comandos você consegue servir o seu projeto React em um servidor estático local.

Ele também tem outras funcionalidades legais que você pode usar (Server-Side Rendering, Static Exporting, etc ...)

1. Para começar:

```
npm install --save next react react-dom
```

2. Adicionar ao package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  }
}
```

3. Criar um arquivo no diretório `./pages/index.js`

```
function Home() {
  return <MeuComponenteReact></MeuComponenteReact>;
}

export default Home;
```

4. E rodar o projeto:

```
npm run dev
```

5. Depois basta acessar http://localhost:3000

Docs: https://nextjs.org/docs